# Why does is_numeric(NAN) return TRUE?

Tags: php, nan

I have tested the `is_numeric` function in the `NAN` constant in PHP and the given result

```
is_numeric(NAN); // TRUE
```

But NAN means "Not A Number". Why the function `is_numeric` returns `true`?

I know that NAN is of `float` type. But when testing the two cases below, the results are different:

```
is_float(NAN) // true
filter_var(NAN, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)// false
```

Why ocurred it?

<sub>Sorry, my english is bad</sub>

Comment: it seems utterly inane to me that "NOT A NUMBER" is numeric.  by inane, i mean stupid. i get the science, but there should be a one-off line of code within `is_numeric` that takes this into consideration and _rights the wrong_...cause _it's wrong_.

Answer (score 4):

`NAN` is a special constant. It has to hold some value, so it holds a `float` *datatype*

```
var_dump(NAN); // float(NAN);
```

The problem is that `filter_var` isn't comparing data types, it's looking for numbers, which `NAN` [is not](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

> Some numeric operations can result in a value represented by the constant NAN. This result represents an undefined or unrepresentable value in floating-point calculations. Any loose or strict comparisons of this value against any other value, including itself, will have a result of FALSE.
>
> Because NAN represents any number of different values, NAN should not be compared to other values, including itself, and instead should be checked for using is_nan().

Answer (score 1):

NAN is a non-zero floating point value. What is NAN, Its a square root of `(-1)`.

So now it comes to complex numbers. Square root of `(-1)` is `+i` or `-i` which means NAN can have two values. So if `NAN` were to evaluate to `-i` or `false`, `NAN == false` would become true instead.